# Вопрос по LL-парсеру

Tags: парсер

Статья
[link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser)

> In each step, the parser reads the next-available symbol from the input stream, and the top-most symbol from the stack. If the input symbol and the stack-top symbol match, the parser discards them both, leaving only the unmatched symbols in the input stream and on the stack.
> Thus, in its first step, the parser reads the input symbol '(' and the stack-top symbol 'S'.

Вопрос, что, собственно, загружается в стек, в каком порядке, и почему на вершине стека именно символ 'S'?

Answer (score 2):

Вы Parsing procedure читаете? Там чуть выше написано, что происходит, а чуть ниже - пример того, как это происходит. S - начальный символ. Насколько я помню, если по правилам грамматики из начального символа может получиться данная строка - значит она удовлетворяет грамматике

Comment: Почему S начальный символ? почему не F? Не '('?

Comment: > where $ is a special terminal to indicate the bottom of the stack and the end of the input stream, and S is the start symbol of the grammar.

Просто выбранное автором статьи обозначение стартового символа в грамматике:

    S → F
    S → ( S + F )
    F → a

Comment: Nofate, а как понять где в моей грамматике будет стартовый символ? http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html

Comment: Видимо, translation_unit - смотря чему Ваша входная строка соответствует

Comment: @Михаил М, видимо, чему она соответствует, должен определять парсер, не так ли?

Comment: Если под парсером понимать машинку, обрабатывающую строку в соответствии с правилами, плюс метод, запускающий данную машинку с некоторой грамматикой на некоторых данных, то, я думаю, это должен определять тот, кто пишет вторую часть.

Comment: @Михаил М, а вообще корректно будет парсить программы, написанные на языке Си с помощью LL-анализатора?

Comment: Я не знаю, подождите ответов других. [Скорее всего нет][1]. Можно, в принципе, и отдельным вопросом оформить. 

[1]: http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEEQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F243383%2F&ei=PAWeUrKTE5LBygP2noDYDw&usg=AFQjCNHbRNWaCKwbKKIvhA8Im68dRRQmtA&sig2=GAXc1_MGAggjCjLMsxHMtw

Comment: @SoloMio начальный символ — не первый символ в строке, а начальный символ грамматики, символ, с которого начинается вывод строк, удовлетворяющих этой грамматике.